# Make a style for the datagrid.columns

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, binding

I'm still struggling on something. All examples i see on the internet apply datagrid.columns in the resources of the datagrid itself. I don't want that. I want to define a template or style in the window.resources which has to apply to the datagrid through binding. Can i and how can i do that? This is the xaml in my control's resources :

```
        <DataGrid Name="dgFruit" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Style="{StaticResource datagrid}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Color}" Header="Color"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Mjummy}" Header="Mjummy"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" Header="Number"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Pits.Count}" Header="Pits"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to apply via window level style for DataGrid columns?

Comment: i want to be able to apply a template to several datagrid, because in 1 window, there are several panes, which can contain identical columns and data. For the moment being, i'm just learning all about the templates/styles, and i'm trying to apply it to existing or in development projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that as far as i know since there is no set-accessor for the `DataGrid.Columns` property, otherwise it could be set in a Style using a Setter.

You can only set columns directly, you cannot bind them using a collection either it seems.

Here is a very roundabout and ugly way to get the same columns in multiple grids:

Resources:

```
<x:Array x:Key="MyColumns" Type="{x:Type DataGridColumn}">
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Color}" Header="Color"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Mjummy}" Header="Mjummy"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" Header="Number"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Pits.Count}" Header="Pits"/>
</x:Array>
```

Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ... Loaded="dataGrid_Loaded"/>
```

Event:

```
private void dataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridColumn[] columns = Resources["MyColumns"] as DataGridColumn[];
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    dg.Columns.Clear();
    foreach (var item in columns)
    {
        dg.Columns.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: is doable, but i have come to the conclusion that some things should just go in the control resources...

Answer (score 0):

You can also add your `Datagrid` in your `UserControl.`/`Window.Resources` and then use a `ContentControl` passing the `DataContext` to it.

Notice the use of `x:Key="MyDataGrid"` and `x:Shared="False"`

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Key="MyDataGrid" x:Shared="False" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Style="{StaticResource datagrid}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Color}" Header="Color"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Mjummy}" Header="Mjummy"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" Header="Number"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Pits.Count}" Header="Pits"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then in your view, you can call this by doing:

```xml
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyDataGrid}" DataContext="{Binding MyFirstData}" />
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyDataGrid}" DataContext="{Binding MySecondData}" />
```